# How come when I create a new version of my model in Ruby on Rails, it does not send the id to the edit and show actions?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nomethoderror

When I run my Ruby on Rails blog app, create a new article and attempt to save it, I get the following error "NoMethodError in Articles#Show". The reason seems to be that when my create an article and attempt to save it, it is not passing the id to the show action. I am getting a similar error when I try to edit a post as well. How can I fix this error?  Below is the code for my Articles Controller and my view for Articles#New.

```
class ArticlesController < ApplicationController
    def create
        @article = Article.new(article_params)

        if @article.save
            redirect_to @article
        else
            render 'new'
        end
    end

    def show
        @article = Article.find(params[:id])
    end

    def edit
        @article = Article.find(params[:id])
    end
end

//code for View

<%= form_for :article, url: articles_path do |f| %>

<p>
    <%= f.label :title %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :title %>
</p>

 <p>
 <%= f.label :text %><br>
 <%= f.text_area :text %>
</p>

<p>
    <%= f.submit %>
</p>
<% end %>
```

I really appreciate the help!

Answer (score 2):

```
<%= form_for :article, url: articles_path do |f| %>
```

should be

```
# view file
<%= form_for @article do |f| %>

# articles_controller.rb
def new
  @article = Article.new
end
```

The first version is not incorrect per se, it's just used in other circumstances. The second one pulls the data from the `@article` variable into the form and then configures the form according to whether it's for creation or updating.

More in the [documentation for form_for](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/form_for)

Comment: I appreciate the help. Unfortunately, that did not fix the problem. It looks like when my app tries to render in the show view, it thinks the article it is trying to show is Nil and needs an ID.

Comment: You should get the ID from the params[:id] for the show action, how are you going about doing that?